# How to make nested field in Firestore with Java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I would like to make a nested field in Firestore with Java.
https://javascript.tutorialink.com/how-to-add-data-to-a-nested-object-in-firestore/
(like this picture in the link)

I looked through the Firebase documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```
// Assume the document contains:
// {
//   name: "Frank",
//   favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" }
//   age: 12
// }
//
// To update age and favorite color:
db.collection("users").document("frank")
        .update(
                "age", 13,
                "favorites.color", "Red"
        );
```

This is what I found, but it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly would you like to store in a nested field?

Comment: I want to store specific data into that. For example, 
User(collection ) > Jessie (document) > Favorites(field) > color:red (subfield) & food:pizza(subfield) ...

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve that?